# Firebird 1.5.6 + Delphi 7 network connectivity

Tags: delphi, network-programming, firebird, freeze

Does anybody has problems with Delphi 7 application and Firebird 1.5.6 when the database is placed on the remote machine in local network ?

The client and the server machines are running Windows 7 OS. It happens periodically. The client application loses connectivity with the server.

I open a connection to the server on the application start up. I don't know what is happening here. My client uses the application, opens the Delphi form fills some data and walks away for 20 minutes. When he returns decides to finish filling the form and after that wants to save the content. On Save button the application freezes.

I think that the connection is lost. Why, and how ?

Is it possible to get an exception or event when the connection is lost? 
Is it possible to find out if the connection is active before save procedure ?

Am I wrong to leave connection open all the time or is better to open connection before every request and close after that?
If yes, the connecting phase takes some time not too much but enough to sense it.

May be the solution is in setting up operating system network timeouts. 
But where and how ?

**EDIT : Another case**
In addition to described situation it happens from time to time when the application starts it takes sometimes 1 or 2 minutes to open connection to the remote Firebird database. I designed it to open connection when application starts. After that period of time evreything works fine. I mean the application does not crashes but again happens the freezing problem.
Why sometimes takes so long to connect, I don't know?

Comment: wifi connection? performs a test network cable

Comment: Unless Cosmin is right (you created and started a transaction immediately at startup?) you will have to step into your code or add some logging to your code and find out exactly WHERE it is freezing up and then maybe, you might be able to find out why.  There could be any number of thousands of things happening as a consequence of clicking Save. Debugging means finding which line of code (not button click) is freezing.

Comment: I have an internal Log but when this freezing happens at that point the logging fails. I tried to log in a file but nothing. The problem happens at the point where I am doing something with database. Before every DB operation I check if the transaction is active and if not I start it again. May be the only way will be to install Delphi development environment and debug but it is not easy because it is my customer's computer.

Comment: The problem occurs only in the networking environment only. The funny part of the story is that I can't reproduce the problem in my development environment. I works whole night without problems.

Comment: It seems obvious, but what components are you using? IBX?
Also, what looks like the firebird.log file?

Comment: If your logging component is also freezing, have you considered that the computer that is having the problem is having fundamental low level problems and that the computer needs hardware repair or an OS reinstallation?

Comment: I alredy chacked that. It is a new computer. We installed the complete operating system again. Checked firewalls, antivirus systems but nothing found. This becomes a very strange problem. Maybe the network switch or wires but other aplications are working correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave `TIbDatabase` connected for as long as you want, it'll auto-re-connect if it loses it's connection. And if you're in a networked situation, it *will* lose it's connection when idle.

You shouldn't keep `TIbTransaction` active for a long time because of Firebird's Multi Generational Architecture: when you change something in a Firebird table, a new record of that "something" is created, keeping all old records alive as long as there's at least one active transaction lingering along.

My guess at what's happening: You've got the TIbTransaction idle for 20 minutes, the TIbDatabase connections got dropped leaving your Transaction into an unknown state.

Comment: I will check your suggestions but I can't understand why it happens only when my client application runs on Windows 7. This problem started bothering me from the beginning of the year. I have many transactions and I check them before every SQL operation. Something like `if not query1.Transaction.InTransaction then query1.Transaction.Commit;`

Comment: Let's suppose you are right but I don't understand why the database connection and consequently the related transactions became inactive when I created a Timer and started to retrieve a small quantity of records every 10 seconds. I made this only in order to retain the connection. The problem has remained.

Comment: Try @rstrelba 's suggestion of changing the DummyPacketInterval to first make sure the problem is truly related to the network connection getting lost. In the absence of any traffic your TCP sessions to the Firebird server would simply expire, and they'll expire in unpredictable ways. The server itself might "time out", any router along the way might time out, even the Firewall that's running on the Windows 7 box might time out the TCP connection. It might happen that both the server and the client consider the TCP session still active, yet one firewall along the way might drop traffic.

Comment: Once you figure out why your connections are timing-out, you should probably make it so transactions don't stay open for too long, turning this into a non-issue. I would not consider the edit to firebird.conf to be a solution: I prefer my Firebird applications to run on stock Firebird configurations: makes deployment and management easier.

Comment: I agree with you but how will I close the transaction in a form that must be opened for a long time. If I close it all the DB components will lose their content. I hope the solution will be simple.

Comment: You either stop using db aware controls or use something intermediary, like DataSnap (MIDAS).

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit firebird.conf file

1) Find parameter DummyPacketInterval, remove "#" and change to DummyPacketInterval = 60
2) Restart Firebird

Answer (score 0):

check your power management option on your clients network adapter driver.
under device manager,the default value is turn device off to save power